# Save & remove rows in a pandas dataframe based on a condition. Error: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe as below (a representation of a much larger dataset) which has a `code` as a column along with another column (acutal dataset as many more).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123456, 123758, 12334356, 4954968, 774853],
                   'col2': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

**Question:** How can I store in a separate dataframe & remove from the original dataframe the entries of this dataframe (all columns associated with the entry as well) which don't have the first 3 characters as `123`?

**Attempted:** To do this I have attempted to select out all rows which start with `123` and then use the not symbol `~` to select everything which doesn't start with this. I have stored this in a new dataframe since I want it saved and then tried dropping this from the original dataframe by getting its index as its not wanted.

```
# Converting column to a string
df['code'] = df['code'].astype(str)

# Saving entries which DONT start with 123 in a separate dataframe
df2 = df[~df['code'].str[0:3] == '123']

# Dropping those bad entries (starting with 123 chars) from dataframe
df = df.drop(df2.index, inplace=True)
```

However when I do this I come across the following error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'
```

Any alternate solutions along with corrections to my own would be much appreciated.

**Desired Output:** Should generalise for additional entries too. Notice that `4954968 & 774853` have gone since they don't start with `123`

```
df_final = pd.Dataframe(df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123456, 123758, 12334356, ], 'col2': [1,2,3]}))
```

Comment: You are missing the brackets. Check `df2 = df[~(df['code'].str[:3] == '123')]`

Answer (score 0):

In your solution is problem priority operators, so is necessary parentheses:

```
df2 = df[~(df['code'].str[0:3] == '123')]
print (df2)
      code  col2
3  4954968     4
4   774853     5
```

Better is change logic - select only matched values

```
df = df[(df['code'].str[0:3] == '123')]
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startswith` to identify the rows that you want. No need for a double negative.

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.loc[df['code'].str.startswith('123'), :]
```